# Not able to get values when using PostBackURL in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page with a textbox and a button. I have set a postbackurl on this button and written the following code on the load event of destination page:

```
if (PreviousPage != null)
        {
            string name = ((TextBox)PreviousPage.FindControl("TextBox1")).Text;

            Response.Write(name);
        }
```

While using debugger, I found that I get following error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I am not able to figure out where the problem is because when I hover on PreviousPage, I can see the first page name and when I see the value of TextBox1 it shows `{System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox}` and not the value that I have entered!

Comment: what are you using to transfer on page to another. `Server.Transfer` or `Response.Redirect()`

Comment: Neither of the two...have only set PostBackURL property of the button control on the first page to abc.aspx. and written the above code on the second page's load event.

Comment: ok.. you are using context handler..

Comment: well according to my info, m not using context handler! may be I am wrong as I am new to web forms. I am only aware of this one.

Comment: provide your previous page markup..  and receiving page name

Comment: refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx)

Comment: After going through your second this reference above, I want to tell you that both of my forms are using same master page layout. So, do I need to first refer to a particular master page or content placeholder and then refer to the textbox control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now able to get the value of textbox. when using a aspx page with a master page, we need to get the reference of the contentplaceholder first and then use that reference to get the reference of textbox.

```
ContentPlaceHolder Content1 =(ContentPlaceHolder)PreviousPage.Master.FindControl("MainContent");
            TextBox SourceTextBox =
    (TextBox)Content1.FindControl("TextBox1");
       Response.Write(SourceTextBox.Text);
```

This will print the value of textbox.text.

Answer (score 0):

When setting the `PostBackUrl`, you're actually posting the form to the destination page. This means that you should be able to access the value using `Request.Form`:

```
string value = Request.Form["MyTextBoxValue"].ToString();
```

If the form method is `GET`, you should be able to access the values through the `QueryString`.

**EDIT**

If you just need to submit the form to another page, you might also consider changing the form `action` to point to the destination page. Then you'll be able to access the values using the `Request` object.

Comment: I have tried using your method, but it doesn't work with PostBackURL.

Comment: Have you tried just changing the form action and method, instead of using the `PostBackUrl`?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not getting the value of the text box using your code is because you are not using .ToString() after .Text. It needs to be:

```
if (PreviousPage != null)
    {
        string name = ((TextBox)PreviousPage.FindControl("TextBox1")).Text.ToString();

        Response.Write(name);
    }
```

Try that and see if it works!