# ASP.NET Friendly URLs PostBackUrl RequestType is comes as GET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, postback, friendly-url

I am trying use PostBackUrl to get the values from previous page but no values are coming from previous page then I checked in the PageLoad what type of request coming in, is showing as GET

First page

```
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" PostBackUrl="~/SecondPage" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Second page

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     string type= Request.RequestType; // comes as GET
     Label1.Text = Request.Form["TextBox1"];
    }
```

Why is come as GET ? how can I get the value of the Texbox1?

**EDIT:**
I HAVE FOUND THAT GET IS COMING BECAUSE OF ASP.NET Friendly URLs. WHAT CAN I DO TO WORK ON ASP.NET Friendly URLs

Please advice me

thanks

Comment: Have you tried Request.Parameters. Maybe loop through it and see what it brings back

Comment: There is nothing call Request.Parameters. Request.Param there not that is different

Comment: I meant Request.Param. Is your ID "TextBox1" on the client side

Comment: I need to access in code behind. Why is GET when I do a post?????

Answer (score 0):

**Why is come as GET?** Check your form declaration. Are you set the form method ?

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" method="get">
</form>
```

**How can I get the value of the Texbox1?**

Because it's a GET request, use [Request.QueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). [Request.Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is used for POST request.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    string type= Request.RequestType; // comes as GET
    Label1.Text = Request.QueryString["TextBox1"];
 }
```

Anyway, another way to store value from first page to second page is using [ASP.NET Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Session["textbox1"] = TextBox1.Text;
}
```

In second page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Label1.Text = Session["textbox1"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: there is no need a method type in my form (AS YOU KNOW DEFAULT FORM METHOD IS POST IN ASP.NET ) and when I change the method to post then also is comes as GET

Answer (score 0):

When the URL rewriter redirects it changes a post to a get.

To change the behavior, in the RouteConfig.cs file set the redirect mode to off.

```
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;
```

If you don't want the extensions from showing you must remove them from your references.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following with cross-page posting

```
((TextBox)PreviousPage.FindControl("TextBox1")).Text;
```

Comment: Have a look here. It could be something to do with your masterpage and you having to reference the contentplaceholder

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801091/not-able-to-get-values-when-using-postbackurl-in-aspx-page